# Can I delete a logical partition to extend another logical drive

Tags: partitioning, grub, windows-8

As you can see from the image below, I am running out of space on Win 8. I want to get rid of Win 7 so I can allocate all its space to Win 8. Can I just simply delete Win 7 logical partition and extend? What are the repercussions, if any, doing this? I also use both grub bootloader and Windows (8) bootloader (boots up to grub then I choose windows which will go to windows boot options). Lastly, is it better to do this on Win XP and use a third-party partition software to delete Win7 and extend Win8? Or be on Win8 and accomplish the same thing through Win8 disk management utility (does it matter either way)? Please let me know any concerns I may ran into and/or recommend the best way to accomplish what I want to do.

Thank you in advance and I hope I wasn't too confusing!

[My Logical Partitions Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4qUm.png)

Comment: Yes you can just delete it. As mentioned in [extend a basic volume](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771473(v=ws.11).aspx): "You can extend a logical drive within contiguous free space in the extended partition that contains it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the Win 7 logical partition on Win 8 using Disk Management. In case DM won't work, then you may rely on a third-party partition software like aomei partition manager, minitool partition wizard and easeus partition master, etc. sort of programs.